# How to change the default content in piwik?

Tags: matomo

I want to give custom dashboard for my subscribing customers.How can i edit the default content in piwik web analytics.I don't know which file i have to edit?please tel me anyone who knows..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can follow the steps as shown in the picture below.
[image]

Then different user can have different layout as you wished.